# Residual autocorrelation on panel data linear regression

Tags: regression, time-series, panel-data, autocorrelation, residuals

I'm trying to fit a model for some yearly count data ´Y´ for different counties from 1990 to 2006. My Y variable is normally distributed, but after fitting the regression the residuals look like this for each year:
[image]

There seems to be a pattern and the residuals appear to be autocorrelated. After looking into this online, I obtained the Durbin-Watson statistic and I get an autocorrelation of 0.06576878, and a D-W statistic of 1.867567 with a p-value of 0.016, which I believe confirms the residuals are autocorrelated.

I've tried several things, like adding a lagged Y_{i - 1} term and doing other transformations to my Y, but I haven't been able to fix this.

I'm not very experienced with this and I'm just wondering how bad it is for my model to have residuals like this if I'm not trying to make any predictions with it. Is there anything else I could try?